# Iterative Algorithm with OpenCL

Tags: algorithm, opencl, iteration

I try to implement a simple algorithm in preperation of a more complex one.
I want to call a kernel several times and it shall increment each value within an array by let's say 5 in each call.

So when I have initially the array [1,2,3,4] I want [6,7,8,9] after the first call and [11,12,13,14] after the second call and so on. But I don't unterstand how to configure my buffers and how to enqueue my buffer in that case. I tried to orient at this tutorial:
http://www.browndeertechnology.com/docs/BDT_OpenCL_Tutorial_NBody-rev3.html
(this is the algorithm I want to implement in the end with some modifications)
but the library used there hides the most important aspects.

At the moment I create my buffer with:

> pos2g_buf = clCreateBuffer(
>                  context,
>                  CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, 
>                 sizeof(cl_float) * (nparticle*4),
>                 pos2g,
>                 &status);

The calls of the Kernel are placed within a for-loop

> for(int i=0; i

And there I set the kernel arguments and call it by:

> ```
>   status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(                                                                                                                                    
>       oclm->commandQueue,                                                                                                                              
>                               kernel,                                                                                                                                    
>                               NDRangeDimension,                                                                                                                                         
>                               NULL,                                                                                                                                      
>                               globalThreads,                                                                                                                             
>                               localThreads,                                                                                                                              
>                               0,                                                                                                                                         
>                               NULL,                                                                                                                                      
>                               &events[0]); //
> ```

Can someone please help me and give the correct (pseudo-) code, how to create my simple iterator program?

Many thanks in advance!
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Host side:

```
cl_mem buffer = clCreateBuffer(..., CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, ...);
cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(...);

clSetKernelArg(.., kernel, buffer, ...);

for(int i=0; i<num_laps; i++){
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(..., kernel, ...);
}

void *host_mem = malloc(...);
clEnqueueReadBuffer(..., buffer, ..., host_mem, ...);
```

On Device side:

```
void __kernel my(global int* mem)
{
    mem[get_global_id(0) += 5;
    return;
}
```

Don't forget to check return codes and release resources.